# How do I call a webdriver without an error?

Tags: selenium, module, python-3.9

I am entering these codes, but I do not know why this error gives me help. Please, what is the solution?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.chrome()
driver.get('https://digikala.com/')
```

error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `webdriver.Chrome()` (with a capital 'C')?

Comment: Additionally to comment above: `from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='your_path')`